# Check which OpenGL engine is used by Qt at runtime for release builds

Tags: windows, qt, opengl, qtquick2, qt5.6

In QML applications [there are 3 rendering types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers):

- Native OpenGL: "desktop"
- ANGLE Direct3D: "angle"
- A software renderer: "software"

We use the automatic loading mechanism of the supported type.

How can I programmatically determine which rendering type is used at runtime?

I know of [QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.qpa.gl=true](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/11/27/qt-weekly-21-dynamic-opengl-implementation-loading-in-qt-5-4/) but this produces a lot of noise and DEBUG messages, which are not logged in our release build. Is there another simple way to just get the rendering type?

Comment: With "software" do you mean through a software OpenGL renderer like Mesa's llvmpipe, or the 2D renderer of Qt Quick?

Comment: @peppe Mesa's llvmpipe via the shipped opengl32sw.dll

Comment: Then can you just check `GL_VENDOR`, `GL_VERSION` etc.? You'll get ANGLE, Mesa, etc.

Comment: @peppe How do I do that? `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)` gives me `null` (on Linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it thanks to @peppe and some additional research:

```
// this connection must be established before show() is called
QObject::connect(window, &QQuickWindow::sceneGraphInitialized,
                 [=] () -> void {
    auto context = window->openglContext();
    auto functions = context->functions();
    const std::string vendor = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(functions->glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    const std::string renderer = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(functions->glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    const std::string version = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(functions->glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    qDebug() << "OpenGL vendor: " << vendor << " "
             << "renderer: " << renderer << " "
             << "version: " << version;
});
```

where `window` is my main QQuickWindow*.